# Import CSV File as input in logstash and pass the output data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-5

I am new to elastic search and I am trying to import data from csv to elasticsearch using logstash and want to show output in kibana. I am using the below logstash conf file.

```
input {
 file {
  path => ["D:/AnalyticsTool/Exe/logstash-5.2.0/logstash-5.2.0/bin/data.csv"]
  type => "core2"
  start_position => "beginning" 
 }
}
filter {
 csv {
  separator => ","
  columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]
 }
 mutate {convert => ["High", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Open", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Low", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Close", "float"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Volume", "float"]}
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  action => "index"
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "stock"
  workers => 1
  user => elastic
  password => changeme
 }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug}
}
```

I am not able to visualize in kibana. Do I need to create indexes manually in elasticsearch or will kibana create the above index automatically?

Comment: Do you have any data in Kibana? Are you using X-Pack Security? If not get rid of username and password.